# Is absolute motion inconsistent with homogenous space?

Tags: spacetime, momentum, conservation-laws, symmetry, inertial-frames

I read that homogenous space implies conservation of momentum (according to Noether's theorem) Conservation of momentum is *kinda* the statement that bodies continue moving with constant velocity unless a force is applied.

Suppose we instead lived in a universe where a bunch of frames could be described as absolutely at rest. Suppose anything moving relative to these frames would inevitably start slowing down relative to these frames, and would eventually also come to rest. I guess this implies that physics experiments would produce such results in constant velocity frames from which you could deduce that you were moving.

Though how does this imply that space is not homogenous in this universe? All the origins of these rest frames have equal preference here

Comment: I can't understand your question. It seems pretty obvious to me that space is not homogeneous (in the sense you're using the word) in this universe. What do you mean by "All the origins of these rest frames have equal preference here"?

Comment: @Allure It's not obvious to me. It means that physical laws are invariant when we translate our origin from one rest frame to another

Comment: @Allure In what sense am I using the word according to you? I only mean that physical experiments are the same under origin translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After the comment by @ZeroTheHero I realized my answer is wrong. Here is the explanation of what went wrong. I will delete the answer later**

Conservation of ordinary momentum is implied by homogeneity of space and time, not just space. The most easiest way to see it is by the fact that you can simulate decelerating particle by adding a time dependent term to free particle lagrangian.

E.g. In one dimensional case (for simplicity):
$$L=\frac{mv^2}{2}-ma_0vt.$$
This leads to EoM:
$$ma=ma_0,$$
where $a_0$ is acceleration you want the particle to have, yet the lagrangian is still invariant under spatial translation.

The conserved momentum is this one:
$$p=mv-ma_0t$$
and this momentum does not imply that free bodies continue moving with constant velocities..

**The problem with this statement is that we can just transform to accelerated frame and we are back in ordinary newtonian physics. Thus I did not show anything new, I just rewritten the old physics in an accelerated frame.**

**Edit**

To explain further:

When we deal with symmetries, the newtonian formulation of mechanics is not the best way to do it. Much better way is to use lagrangian mechanics. Here we simple declare function called lagrangian $L$ and we say, that particle will move between points $A$ and $B$ in such a way as to make the action given by this integral along the curve $\gamma(t)$ from $A$ to $B$:
$$S=\int_{\gamma(t)} L dt$$
minimal. Thus to find real movement of the particle, you just need to find which curve from $A$ to $B$ minimizes the integral. This leads to certain equations called equations of motion (EoM) or Euler-Lagrange equations.

Since in mechanics the system is determined once the position and velocities of all particles is known, the lagrangian can in general depend on velocities and positions of the particles and the time. Thus $L=L(\dot{x}_i^j,x_i^j,t)$, where lower index is giving component of the vector and upper which particle we are talking about. In this case, the equations by which particles will move will be given by Euler-Lagrange equations in the form:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_i^j}=\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial x_i^j}.$$

So to recapitulate. In lagrangian mechanics we can give just one function and from the demand of minimalization of action we can arrive at some equations, which for the appropriate lagrangian are the same as traditional newton formula $m\vec{a}=\vec{F}.$

Now, consider some symmetry. For example symmetry under spatial translation (homogeneity of space). This means transformation $t'=t$ and $\vec{x}'=\vec{x}+\vec{\epsilon}$, where $\vec{\epsilon}$ can be any constant vector. If physics should be the same, it means EoM should remain the same and this will happen if the action does not change under the transformation. This requirement of action not being changed by (differentiable) transformation leads to Noether's theorem.

In simple case of lagrangian not being dependent on certain coordinate $x$ with $v=\dot{x}$, the EoM gives:
$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial v}=0$ and it means, that the *generalized momentum* defined as $p\equiv\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial v}$ is conserved.

For ordinary momentum being the same as this conserved current, it must hold that $mv=\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial v}$ which means that $L=mv^2/2+C$, where integration constant $C$ can depend on anything but the velocity $v$. In Newtonian mechanics, the lagrangian is $L=T-U$, where $T$ is kinetic energy and $U$ is potential energy, which in mechanics should not depend on velocities of particles, so the conservation of ordinary momentum is true. For different spatially homogenenous lagrangians, the conserved (due to homogeneity of space) generalized momentum does no longer need to be the same as ordinary momentum.

**Edit2**
However we could just used some random coordinates (this is the point I did not realize in my original answer), which leads to weird form of momentum. The real question then is, wheter in spatially homogenenous universe we can always find coordinates that leads to conservation of ordinary momentum? Sadly I do not have an answer for that.

Comment: I've not yet studied Langranian, so can't understand this at all. Is the real momentum time dependent and we're taught the wrong momentum in introductory physics? And what if our universe just had a set of absolute rest frames, and that a constant and continuous supply of "force" was needed to move anything with constant speed wrt those frames? Would that somehow imply that different absolute positions in the universe would have different properties?

Comment: @RyderRude how do you know about Noether's theorem then?

Comment: I just came across its statement on wikipedia. It said 'Translation symmetry results in momentum conservation and Temporal symmetry in energy conservation'

Comment: @RyderRude ok, I'll try to explain in a brief the whole concept behind noether theorem and lagrangian mechanics. Do you know at least what derivative, intergral and partial derivative is, so that I can use it?

Comment: yes, I know those. Thanks! Please also touch on the implications of having absolute motion in our universe

Comment: @RyderRude the answer is updated.

Comment: I do not understand your analysis.  If $p=m(v-a_0t)$ is conserved, it means $v=(p_0+a_0t)/m$ for initial $p_0$ and thus the body would move with constant velocity with $t$.  Moreover, since $vt=\frac{d}{dt}(qt)- q$, we can remove the explicit time dependence and your Lagrangian is equivalent to  $L=mv^2/2+ma_0q$, which is explicitly position-dependent.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the $v$ you computed is linear function of time, why do you say it is constant? For the second point, this is actually quite interesting and thank you for it. The trick is you can shift to accelerated frame in which both time and spatial dependence disappear, thus I just only introduced accelerated frame, instead of introducing different physics. It seems to me, in one dimension this is the only possibility.I think that in 3D homogeneity of space does not imply the generalized momentum is same (up to coordinate transformation) as $mv,$ but I cannot show it.

Comment: How silly of me... of course $v$ is not constant.  I dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: Please leave your answer for a while.  I'm not sure going to an accelerated frame is "good ole Newtonian physics".   I think your statement at the start indicates clearly there's a subtly in the issue.

Comment: @RyderRude sorry, but the answer you accepted was wrong. Check out the blacked text and edit 2 at the end.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero sure, if you think it is still usefull, I do not need to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that anything moving relative to the "absolute rest" frame decelerates at a constant rate, $a = -x \ m/s^2$, until it is at rest with respect to the "absolute rest" frame. Then, if you are in the absolute rest frame, you will see this deceleration.

If you are not in the absolute rest frame, but one that is moving at constant velocity w.r.t to that frame, you will not see this. In fact if you were originally moving at the same speed as the object (i.e. at the start of the motion you perceive the object to be at rest), you would see it accelerate.

Therefore different observers see different things, and the universe is not homogeneous.

Comment: But don't all the rest frame observers see the same thing in that universe? In our universe too, observers in accelerating frames observe pseudo forces. So different observers see different things here too.

Comment: @RyderRude however, the frames in my answer are inertial frames - in our universe accelerating frames are not inertial, Newton's first law does not hold in them.

Comment: then in that universe, the rest frames are called "inertial" frames. What's the difference? In our universe, homogeneity of space implies physical laws are invariant under translation of origin from one constant speed frame to another. In that universe, it implies that laws of physics are invariant under translation of origin from one rest frame to another

Comment: What if, in that universe, an equivalent of "force" is needed to keep the objects moving with constant speed (wrt the rest frames), and that the object comes to rest instantaneously as this force is removed?

Comment: (-1) Noninvariance under galilean transformations (which you analyze by taking frames with relative velocity) does not imply noninvariance under spatial translations (which is the meaning of homogeneity of space). Spatial translations are but the subset of galilean transformations and the galilean transformation invariance can be spoiled elsewhere (i.e. not in the translation subset), as it is the case in your example.

Comment: @RyderRude I can't understand your question again. In our current universe the laws of motion are the same in all inertial frames, but not accelerated ones, because it's easy to devise an experiment that shows that one is in an accelerated frame. Similarly in the hypothetical universe it's easy to derive an experiment that shows that one is not in the preferred rest frame.

Comment: @RyderRude do remember that in our universe, momentum is not conserved if you are in a non-inertial frame.